# Unable to Get CodeDom dll to build, mismatch Assembly

Tags: asp.net, .net, nuget, .net-assembly, codedom

I am running a 4.6.1 .NET Azure API. I'm trying to debug it locally, and I get this error.

[image]

The exact error says

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Now, I have searched for the standard responses. I checked my package config first: 
[image]

Sure enough, it's the right version of 1.0.2. I then checked my reference to make sure my version is what it says it is. 
[image]

So I check my local assembly just in case as well. Looks on point. 
[image]

So what am I missing? Where else could it not match? The only solution I have found is to point the project's build settings to 'bin\' versus 'bin\debug', but that feels way too hacky.

Answer (score 4):

What worked for me was simply uninstalling that package: Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform

The code worked just fine with out it in my case.  I was able to re-install the package and the code continued to work just fine as well.  Git seems to think all the package files that came back are different to those that were there before uninstall.

I'm not sure why this worked, but it got me developing again.